# VS 2012 Store Create App Packages Disabled

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I would like to **Create App Packages** for my **Windows Store App**, but the **Create App Packages** menu item is disabled. I found this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh454036.aspx

Which states that certain menu items will be disabled under certain conditions, but it doesn't describe what those conditions are.

Is anyone aware of what these conditions are as I cant seem to find more info regarding this.

Comment: This is happening to me on VS2013. Selecting the project isn't helping. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c588a384-ceb8-4bf0-bfa5-548573de799e/visual-studio-store-create-app-packages-disabled

If you have multiple projects in the solution, you need to have a proper project selected in the solution explorer so that all Store options are available.

Comment: I have tested this also by selecting my xamarin.forms based windowsphone's project but the options did not get enabled.
What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too, though It was another developer's code. I didn't know that the person actually created a Windows Phone Silverlight App.
check this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/08/07/why-can-t-i-create-an-app-package-windows-phone-xap-vs-appx.aspx
This link solved the issue for me. So check out to see if you didn't create a Windows Phone Silverlight application when you were selecting from the project templates in New Project dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently for Windows Phone 8 you *dont* create an app package but you rather get the XAP file listed under bin/release. I'm seeing this question asked a ton.

Answer (score 0):

After retargeting my project from Windows Phone 8.0 to 8.1, the store menu is visible