# VS 2013 - Store > Create App Packages Disabled

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to deploy a Windows Phone 8.0 package with VS 2013, in order to upload it to the Store.

I have referred to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh975357.aspx) but the problem is that Project > Store is disabled...

I have searched and found these answers: [Answer 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/he-IL/b94b9199-5ffc-4ddd-b2e8-327a644f5123/visual-studio-store-create-app-packages-disabled?forum=toolsforwinapps), [Answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17353258/vs-2012-store-create-app-packages-disabled). But with no help: even though the correct project is selected in the solution explorer - I still can't use the Store menu items in VS.

Any idea why? Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are looking at a tutorial for Windows Store. Not Windows Phone store.
To upload packages for Windows Phone, you need to build the project and then choose the *.xap you find in `Bin\Release` in the upload process at dev.windowsphone.com.

This does change if you develop an universal application for Windows-Phone8.1/Windows8.1 or an application explicitly for Windows-Phone8.1.

Comment: This was definitely NOT easy to figure out. Thanks

Comment: ...How could this not be explained clearly anywhere on the microsoft site? Literally almost everything says "Create App Package" to submit the file generated...