# Windows Phone 8.0 app packaging in Visual Studio 2015 Preview

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have got Visual Studio 2015 Ultimate Preview installation through my students Dreamspark account. I installed it on top of updated Windows 8.1. workstation.

I have Windows Phone 8.0 application that I need to publish to Windows Phone Store. I am following MS guide on their site, but I am stuck with step in which my options for packaging solution are disabled in VS 2015 Preview (can't start the wizard).

Here is the screenshot of Visual Studio:

[image: Wizard for packaging disabled]

On this site: [http://goo.gl/pjbLPh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLMKA.png) I have found guide for installing  **Tools for Maintaining Store apps for Windows 8** but it is targeting VS 2012 and VS 2013. In my installer for VS 2015 I didn't even see this tool in optional features for install. Maybe the name is changed?

Does anyone have early experiences with VS 2015 Preview and packaging WP 8 apps for Windows Phone Store?

Comment: I guess you have to sign in to Visual studio

Comment: @ZeKoU did you ever resolve this? I have the exact same issue and it is driving me freaking crazy.

Comment: Sorry for a 2nd follow up, but for anyone else who is curious I also came across this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23720748/vs-2013-store-create-app-packages-disabled which I am hoping is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select a Windows Store app project in the solution explorer before.

(You screenshot shows that you currently selected the solution and not a project.)

Comment: Same thing happens when I select either of two projects under solution. Menu for packaging is still disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the distribution option is selected.

Comment: It might be helpful to provide exact guidance on how to do that.

Comment: Don't post this as a vague, unhelpful answer. Please clarify your statement for those of us that actually need to resolve this issue. This answer is incredibly poor quality.