# Visual Studio 2015 RTM Cordova project won't debug/deploy to Android, Windows, Windows Phone

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I've got a feeling I upgraded to Visual Studio 2015 RTM too early.  Visual Studio Emulator for Android would no longer launch, claiming that the pre-release version had expired.

I ran the RTM installer, allowing it to replace Release Candidate components as needed.  The process ran smoothly, but now after upgrading, Cordova projects will no longer deploy or debug.

With the Release Candidate, the toolbar's green Start button had a dropdown for choice of device.  Now with RTM version, this button is just labelled "Start" and its dropdown provides no options for device selection.  Instead, the only option in the dropdown is "Start".  As I change the selection in the "Solution Platform" dropdown, located left of this Start button, the Start button still provides no choices.  See images below.

Solution Platform: Android
[image: Cordova-Android]

Solution Platform: Windows-AnyCPU
[image: Cordova-Windows]

Solution Platform: Windows Phone 8
[image: Cordova-WP]

The Debug menu's "Start Debugging" item is disabled.  If I click the Start toolbar button, I get this message:  "The debugger cannot continue running the process.  Unable to start debugging."

I've confirmed that Visual Studio Emulator for Android is functional.  I've got the profile '5" Lollipop (5.0) XXHDPI Phone' working.

For a comparison, I've also added a new Windows Phone 8.1 project to my solution and confirmed that project allows selecting a Debug Target.  In the toolbar, the word Start is replaced with "Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB".  With this project as the Startup Project, the Debug menu now has "Start Debugging" enabled.  This project starts as expected.

[image: C#-WP81]

Since the Visual Studio Emulator for Android is functional, and Visual Studio successfully targets the Windows Phone emulator, it seems there's a misconfiguration related to Visual Studio's Cordova project type.  The linkage between a VS2015 Cordova project and its "device" targets is missing.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**  See also:  [Unable to start debugging in Visual Studio RTM for cordova app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530014/unable-to-start-debugging-in-visual-studio-rtm-for-cordova-app)

**UPDATE 2:**  I've made several adjustments:

1. Tools for Apache Cordova's Dependency checker found missing Android SDK components.  I've added these, satisfying Dependency Checker.
2. Tools for Apache Cordova's Environment Variable Overrides showed no path to ADT_HOME.  I've set it to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk".
3. My build output showed "[taskdef] could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. it could not be found."  I added a system environment variable ANT_HOME pointing to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3", and added ";%ANT_HOME%\bin" to the PATH.  Still "emma_ant.properties" message remains, but it is not up to the level of a warning or error.

With Solution Platform set to Android, my current build output is:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: BlankCordovaApp2, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Buildfile: C:\Users\billvo\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\build.xml
1>    [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.
1>
1>  -check-env:
1>   [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.0
1>   [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>
1>  -setup:
1>       [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
1>    [gettype] Project Type: Application
1>
1>  -pre-clean:
1>
1>  clean:
1>  [getlibpath] Library dependencies:
1>  [getlibpath]
1>  [getlibpath] ------------------
1>  [getlibpath] Ordered libraries:
1>    [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.
1>
1>  nodeps:
1>
1>  -check-env:
1>   [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 23.0.0
1>   [checkenv] Installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>
1>  -setup:
1>       [echo] Project Name: MainActivity
1>    [gettype] Project Type: Android Library
1>
1>  -pre-clean:
1>
1>  clean:
1>
1>  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
1>  Total time: 0 seconds
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.2 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.0
1>  ------ Package not currently installed globally.
1>  ------ Installing globally from source package. This could take a few minutes...
1>  > edge@0.10.1 install C:\Users\billvo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\node_modules\edge
1>  > node tools/install.js
1>  Success: platform check for edge.js: node.js ia32 v0.12.2
1>  npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
1>  npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.6.2: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
1>  npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
1>  C:\Users\billvo\AppData\Roaming\npm\vs-tac-cli -> C:\Users\billvo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd
1>  vs-tac@1.0.0 C:\Users\billvo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac
1>  ├── rimraf@2.2.6
1>  ├── ncp@0.5.1
1>  ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
1>  ├── q@1.0.1
1>  ├── semver@2.3.1
1>  ├── adm-zip@0.4.4
1>  ├── fstream@0.1.28 (inherits@2.0.1, graceful-fs@3.0.8)
1>  ├── optimist@0.6.1 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
1>  ├── tar@0.1.20 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.8)
1>  ├── elementtree@0.1.6 (sax@0.3.5)
1>  ├── request@2.36.0 (forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, qs@0.6.6, oauth-sign@0.3.0, tunnel-agent@0.4.1, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, mime@1.2.11, node-uuid@1.4.3, tough-cookie@2.0.0, http-signature@0.10.1, hawk@1.0.0, form-data@0.1.4)
1>  ├── ripple-emulator@0.9.30 (connect-xcors@0.5.2, colors@0.6.0-1, open@0.0.3, accounting@0.4.1, request@2.12.0, moment@1.7.2, express@3.1.0)
1>  ├── edge@0.10.1 (edge-cs@0.2.7, nan@1.8.4)
1>  └── plugman@0.22.4 (q@0.9.7, underscore@1.4.4, nopt@1.0.10, rc@0.3.0, cordova-lib@0.21.6, npm@1.3.4)
1>  ------ npm install of vs-tac@1.0.0 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac completed.
1>  ------ Installing Cordova tools cordova@4.3.1 for project from npm. This could take a few minutes...
1>  npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
1>  npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.8.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
1>  npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.2","npm":"2.7.4"})
1>  npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
1>  cordova@4.3.1 node_modules\cordova
1>  ├── underscore@1.7.0
1>  ├── q@1.0.1
1>  ├── nopt@3.0.1 (abbrev@1.0.7)
1>  └── cordova-lib@4.3.1 (valid-identifier@0.0.1, osenv@0.1.0, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.6, mime@1.2.11, unorm@1.3.3, semver@2.0.11, dep-graph@1.1.0, shelljs@0.3.0, rc@0.5.2, through2@0.6.3, npmconf@0.1.16, xcode@0.6.7, elementtree@0.1.5, d8@0.4.4, request@2.47.0, glob@4.0.6, tar@1.0.2, init-package-json@1.7.1, plist@1.1.0, cordova-js@3.8.0, npm@1.3.4)
1>  ------ npm install of cordova@4.3.1 from npm completed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: prepare
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: BlankCordovaApp2
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\billvo\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins:
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
1>  Preparing android project
1>  Processing configuration changes for plugins.
1>  Iterating over installed plugins: []
1>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "BlankCordovaApp2"
1>  deleted: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  splash screens: [{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png","density":"land-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-xhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png","density":"port-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-xhdpi","platform":"android"}]
1>  copying image from C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png to C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png to C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png to C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to C:\Users\billvo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.myapp2a20d4"
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm still not able to select the target device for debugging, regardless of whether I build for Android, Windows-AnyCPU, or Windows Phone 8.

**UPDATE 3:**  The images below show the Visual Studio 2015 components installed.  I tried adding Visual C++ Mobile Development, but saw no change in Cordova, so I removed it.

[image: Add/Remove 1]

[image: Add/Remove 2]

[image: Add/Remove 3]

[image: Add/Remove 4]

**UPDATE 4:**  When I logged into a new local user account, I'm able to debug against the Visual Studio Emulator for Android.  This tells me that the problem is likely specific to my primary Windows account's profile.  I could probably fix this by deleting my profile and starting fresh.

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, except in my case I never installed the VS2015 RC. I already had the latest VS2013 Community installed. Uninstalled 2013 as best I could, installed VS2015 community and get the same debug error for Cordova projects.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Looks like a library is corrupted from the upgrade. Please give this a try:

1. Close all VS instances
2. cd %appdata%\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools”
3. rename CoreCon folder
4. Launch VS again.

Let us know if this resolves your issue.
Thanks for using VS 2015 and Tools for Apache Cordova.

Soak.

Comment: This worked for me, Thx. The same Answer gave Leo one Hour earlier in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530014/unable-to-start-debugging-in-visual-studio-rtm-for-cordova-app/31630494#31630494

Comment: please what is appdata in your case?

Comment: That solved it, thanks. Had repaired then uninstalled/reinstalled VS 2015 the whole day!
MS should really fix that, instead of this stupid error message to rename the CoreCon folder as a suggestive fix.

Comment: Solved for me as well... I was removing VS2013 and corresponding cordova CTPs from the same machine that installed VS2015 RTM.

Comment: @Subhag Oak -- sorry to try and ask an unrelated question but do you have any insight as to why a Visual Studio 2015 project wouldn't be able to create an app package via the Project -> Store menu? Here's the reference to the issue I and others are facing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194022/windows-phone-8-0-app-packaging-in-visual-studio-2015-preview

Comment: @SMT, are you sure you have selected Windows and Device as your options in the debug/platform dropdown? The open is only enabled when Windows platform is selected.

Comment: @SubhagOak thanks for getting back to me. There was confusion on my part I believe. I have an app that I eventually need to submit to the windows store and everything I was reading was talking about creating the app package through project -> store -> create app package. However, for WP8 I apparently just need to grab the XAP file from bin/release. Does this sound correct to you?

Comment: This happened after Update 2 putting Xamarin on top of a Cordova install, days of issues/searching was solved with this answer - thx

Comment: YES this really worked, the installer should be updated to perform the very same task after setup.

Answer (score 2):

The Answer "Subhag Oak" gave, worked for me.

Here the documentation of my research, if it does not work for any other user.

**Watch the output**, to get your specific cause. Increase the build-Verbosity in VS-Options.

**go to Tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova, click the 'Run Dependency Checker'**.

Check the installed Visual Studio features, this is selected by default:

[image: VS for Cordova-Development]

Compared to [msdn:Install Tools for Cordova](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Add also:

- Emulator for Windows Phone 8.1
- Android Native Development Kit (R10E, 32 bits)

And if you still get no emulator after compiling a blank cordova app:

[image: no preinstalled 8.1. Emulator]

I think then you have to install google chrome: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054.aspx)
"The installer does not install Google Chrome, which is required if you want to run the Apache Ripple simulator for iOS and Android, and it does not install Apple iTunes, which is required for deploying an app to an iOS device connected to your Windows PC."

Also check your Hyper-V Settings:

I'm checking out the Tools\Visual Studio Emulator for Android:
[image: Activated Emulator Message]

Check the [SystemRequirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228280.aspx)

Check this link: [Troubleshooting the Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#ADB)

Or give "reinstalling node.js" a chance. Wait for "Setup Repair" again.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  I've worked through these.  They helped me fix some config problems, but the initial problem remains.  I'm not sure what StackOverflow considers a duplicate, but the question you reference focuses specifically on Android, not mentioning Windows and Windows Phone which are also failing here.  You could click "flag" if it has "serious problems."

Comment: Nice updated question. Read your hole output. And will try to give another hint.

Comment: I've added images showing the VS2015 components installed.  I've already got the Windows Phone 8.1 emulator installed and working with an empty WP project, so I don't see "Download Emulator 8.1..."  When you install that, will your Cordova project let you pick that emulator?  I see no options on Start dropdown except "Start".

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above didn't work me. But after searching the net for hours, I came to this solution that worked like a charm:

If the “Tools for Universal Windows Apps Development” are still installed:

1. Go to Programs and Features, select Visual Studio 2105, click Change.
2. In Visual Studio setup, click Modify.
3. Deselect the feature “Tools for Universal Windows App Development”
4. Select “Tools for Universal Windows App Development” again, and click Update.

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c9936d80-087d-4cad-93bf-ca4873889773/the-debugger-cannot-continue-running-the-process?forum=vsdebug

Answer (score 0):

@SubhagOak solution to rename CoreCon folder worked for me too, even tho a slightly different pre-deployment scenario.  Could not deploy from VS2015 to Android device via USB debuging.  Error notification was generated via VS pop up basiclly stating Could Not Find File but no errors were listed in VS Error Console. It only generated a  pop up.  Received this error after opening a new local branch of a newly cloned local GIThub repo created using VS2015 Teamwork Explorer.

This is the second time this solution has worked for me; same scenario.