# Can not use Apache cordova with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, apache-cordova

I'm trying to create a Apache Cordova app via Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, but I can't.
I installed VS 2015 with Apache Cordova tools. Created an Apache Cordova project, opened `project.xml` and tried to add plugins to the app.

But then I get the following error: [log trace at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/rxRHeqxc)

So, previously, I got that error and reinstalled VS 2015, but it is still not working.

EDIT:
I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619211/visual-studio-2015-rtm-cordova-project-wont-debug-deploy-to-android-windows-w)

Comment: The solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619211/visual-studio-2015-rtm-cordova-project-wont-debug-deploy-to-android-windows-w). I just rename the directory.

Answer (score 1):

did you install Apache Cordova tools when you install visual studio 2015.

you should click on custom installation and install Corodva Apache Tools. [image]

Cheers