# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova project now showing up Ripple and other emulation option

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Earlier I used to get multiple options for environment selection like shown in the image for Debug -> Android selection. (Ripple, Device, Google Android Emulator, Ripple - Nexus7 (Tablet), Ripple-Nexus (Galaxy) etc).

However, all of a sudden, now it just shows Start option as shown in top image. I am getting full list in new project, but I an not able to figure out how do I get this for my existing project.

I am using VS 2015 Cordova + ionic. I compared, Build-> Configuration then config.xml and solution files for both the project, but did not find any significant difference.

[image: Debug-> Android Options]

Comment: Does this problem persist on a new blank project?

Comment: No, for blank, it works as normal.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may running into an [issue we've seen before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619211/visual-studio-2015-rtm-cordova-project-wont-debug-deploy-to-android-windows-w/31688404#31688404) (I work in the VS Cordova Tools team). Here are the steps to try, quoted from the above answer:

> 1. Close all VS instances
> 2. [In Explorer, open] "%appdata%\Local\Microsoft\Phone Tools"
> 3. rename the CoreCon folder
> 4. Launch VS again

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I added another project earlier in the same solution. After removing that project, I have to reset the Cordova as startup project. (Though only project on solution is Cordova)